# rounded ends of menu, skewx menu components (border radius, hide overflow, skewx) not working in safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, transform

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3jh23q93/1/

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="testmenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="one"><span><p>ONE</p></span></li>
        <li class="two"><span><p>TWO</p></span></li>
        <li class="three"><span><p>THREE</p></span></li>
        <li class="four"><span><p>FOUR</p></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
.testmenu ul{
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    border-radius: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 95%;
}
.testmenu ul li{
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
.testmenu span{
    transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg);
    display: block;
    color: white;
}
.one{
    padding-left: 40px !important;
    margin-left: -60px !important;
}
.four{
    padding-right: 40px !important;
    margin-right: -30px !important;
}
```

I'm trying to make a menu with rounded ends AND with diagonal dividers between menu options. However, I can't seem to do both. I can either skew them 45 degrees for the diagonals (and skew the contents -45 degrees). OR I can make rounded ends. But if I attempt to do them both, the border radius is not showing. More accurately, the overflow hide is not being done as I would expect. It works on the latest Opera, Chrome, IE, and Firefox. But does not work on Safari 5.1.7 on a Windows machine.

Can anyone clue me into what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: works fine for me only thing i changed is `.testmenu span` to `display:inline-block` http://jsfiddle.net/3jh23q93/2/ mac safari 7.1.2

Comment: strange...your fiddle is not working on safari 5.1.7 on my windows laptop. :(